# In android where the description in config.xml used for

Tags: android, cordova

We could see the config.xml inside android project res\xml folder.  In that file there is a tag called description.  Where the description content is used for?

I build the application using Phonegap and that puts a default description.  I am wondering whether do I need to change the description?

Answer (score 0):

From the PhoneGap documentation:

> The description and author elements specify metadata and contact information that may appear within app-store listings.

Link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_index.md.html

Comment: I refer this page before posting my question. Do they mean Google play store?  I dont think so, because the description and other contact details will be captured in play store while uploading and publishing the APK.

Comment: I understand the description in config.xml is only applicable when you build the phonegap via build.phonegap website.